# Cartrader program. 1 Junit error left but I don´t understand

Tags: java

Eclipse shows the error "The primitive type byte of Vehicle does not have a field PASSENGER_CAR" in my  "Vehicle class". What does it mean?  It´s the only error left in the JUnit test we have to use in class. When i write "7" or "5" which are the constants for the types it seems to  work, but I´m not allowed to do that.   Here is the full program:

```
public class Vehicle {

public static final float TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR = 40.f;
public static final float TANK_SIZE_TRUCK = 80.f;
private float fuel;
private  float VehicleType;


public Vehicle(){

}

public Vehicle(byte VehicleType){

    this();
    if (VehicleType == VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR){
        this.VehicleType= VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR ;
        this.fuel= Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR;
    }

    if(VehicleType == VehicleType.TRUCK){
        this.VehicleType= VehicleType.TRUCK;
        this.fuel= Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK;
    }

    public float getFuel(){
        return fuel;
    }
    public byte getVehicleType(){
        return VehicleType;


    }

}
```

}

```
public final class VehicleType {

public static final byte PASSENGER_CAR = 7;

public static final byte TRUCK = 5;


/**
 * This class is just an organizer for the above constants; Not instantiable.
 */
private VehicleType(){

}
```

}

```
public class CarTrader {

public static final float CAPACITY_DIESEL_LITERS = 250.f;
public static final float CAPACITY_GAS_LITERS = 180.f;
public static final int CAPACITY_PASSENGER_CARS = 15;
public static final int CAPACITY_TRUCKS = 5;


float gasStockLiters=180.f;
float dieselStockLiters=250.f;
int passengerCarsStock=15;
int trucksStock=5;

void setGasStockLiters(float gasStockLiters){
    this.gasStockLiters=gasStockLiters;
}

void setDieselStockLiters(float dieselStockLiters){
    this.dieselStockLiters=dieselStockLiters;
}

void setPassengerCarsStock(int passengerCarsStock){
    this.passengerCarsStock=passengerCarsStock;
}

void setTrucksStock(int trucksStock){
    this.trucksStock=trucksStock;
}

int getPassengerCarsStock(){
    return passengerCarsStock;
}

int getTrucksStock(){
    return trucksStock;
}
float getGasStockLiters(){
    return gasStockLiters;
}
float getDieselStockLiters(){
    return dieselStockLiters;
}



public Vehicle sellVehicle(byte vehicleType){

Vehicle soldVehicle=null;


    switch (vehicleType){



    case 0: //VehicleType.TRUCK: 

        if(this.dieselStockLiters>=Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK && this.trucksStock>=1){

            trucksStock = trucksStock - 1;
            dieselStockLiters = dieselStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR;
            soldVehicle = new Vehicle(VehicleType.TRUCK);
            System.out.println("LKW erfolgreich verkauft");

        }
            else{
                soldVehicle=null;
            }

        break;

    case 1://VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR:

        if(gasStockLiters>=Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR && this.passengerCarsStock>=1){

            passengerCarsStock = passengerCarsStock - 1;
            gasStockLiters = gasStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR;

            soldVehicle = new Vehicle(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR);
            System.out.println("PKW erfolgreich verkauft");

    }
        else{
            soldVehicle=null;
        }

    break;

    default:

        break;
}
    return soldVehicle;
```

}

```
public Vehicle[] sellVehicles(byte vehicleType, int amount){

    Vehicle[] soldVehicles = new Vehicle[amount];
    float currentAmount=40*amount;
    float currentAmount2=80*amount;



    switch (vehicleType){


    case 0://VehicleType.TRUCK: 

        if(this.dieselStockLiters>=currentAmount2 && this.trucksStock>=amount){

            trucksStock = trucksStock - amount;
            dieselStockLiters = dieselStockLiters - (currentAmount2);

            for (int i=0; i<amount; i++){

                soldVehicles[i]=new Vehicle(VehicleType.TRUCK);
            }


            System.out.println("LKW erfolgreich verkauft");

        }
            else{
                soldVehicles=null;
            }

        break;




    case 1://VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR:


        if(this.gasStockLiters>=currentAmount && this.passengerCarsStock>=amount){

            passengerCarsStock = passengerCarsStock - amount;
            gasStockLiters = gasStockLiters - (currentAmount);

            for (int i=0; i<amount; i++){

                soldVehicles[i]=new Vehicle(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR);
            }

            System.out.println("PKW erfolgreich verkauft");

    }
        else{
            soldVehicles=null;
        }

    break;

    default:
        soldVehicles=null;
        break;
    }


    return soldVehicles;
}


public boolean fillGas(float gas){

    boolean filled=false;

    if((gasStockLiters + gas)<=CarTrader.CAPACITY_GAS_LITERS){

        gasStockLiters = gasStockLiters + gas;
        filled=true;
    }
        else{
            System.err.println("Die Kapazität beträgt höchstens 180 Liter");
        }
    return filled;
    }

public boolean fillDiesel(float diesel){

    boolean  filled2=false;

    if((dieselStockLiters + diesel)<=CarTrader.CAPACITY_DIESEL_LITERS){

        dieselStockLiters = dieselStockLiters + diesel; 
        filled2=true;
    }

        else{
            System.err.println("Die Kapazität beträgt höchstens 250 Liter");
        }
    return filled2;
}

public boolean reorderVehicles(byte vehicle, int amountVehicles){

    boolean full=false;

    if (vehicle==1){

        if ((trucksStock + amountVehicles)<=CarTrader.CAPACITY_TRUCKS){

            trucksStock = trucksStock + amountVehicles;
            full=true;
        }

    }

    if (vehicle==0){

        if ((passengerCarsStock + amountVehicles)<=CarTrader.CAPACITY_PASSENGER_CARS){

            passengerCarsStock = passengerCarsStock + amountVehicles;
            full=true;
        }

    }
        else {
            System.out.println("Bitte 5 oder 7 wählen");
        }
    return full;
    }

void statusOutput()
{
    System.out.println("AutoHändler - Lagerbestand:");
    System.out.println("    PKW: " + passengerCarsStock);
    System.out.println("    - Benzin: " + gasStockLiters);
    System.out.println("    LKW: " + trucksStock);
    System.out.println("    - Diesel: " + dieselStockLiters);
}
```

}

Comment: You should have a compilation error no? What is the stacktrace of it? Eclipse should show you the exact spot of the error normally.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] (with the empahsis on **minimal**). In your case, the problem stems from `Vehicle`'s constructor `public Vehicle(byte VehicleType)`: variable `VehicleType` is of type `byte` and a `byte` (being a primitive) does not have a field `PASSENGER_CAR`. You hide the `class VehicleType` with the parameter `byte VehicleType`.

Comment: @SMA you sure this is the problem? Form the question, it seems that the compiler acutally complains about `Vehicletype.PASSENGER_CAR` within `Vehicle`'s constructor (haven't checked it myself though).

Comment: Woops! Actually OP used this `public Vehicle(byte VehicleType){

    this();
    if (VehicleType == VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR){` And he has another class called VehicleType!

Answer (score 1):

You have a class named `VehicleType`, a float named `VehicleType`, and pass in a byte named `VehicleType` into the function.  Change your `Vehicle` initualizer to `public Vehicle(byte vehicleType)`, and the error should go away, stop naming everything `VehicleType`.

```
public class Vehicle {
    public static final float TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR = 40.f;
    public static final float TANK_SIZE_TRUCK = 80.f;
    private float fuel;
    private float mVehicleType;

    public Vehicle(){}

    public Vehicle(byte vehicleType){
        this();
        if (vehicleType == VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR){
            this.mVehicleType= VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR ;
            this.fuel= Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR;
        }

        if(vehicleType == VehicleType.TRUCK){
            this.mVehicleType= VehicleType.TRUCK;
            this.fuel= Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK;
        }
    }

    public float getFuel(){
        return this.fuel;
    }

    public byte getVehicleType(){
        return this.mVehicleType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would just say `byte type`, and lowercase the field name

Comment: @cricket_007 to-ma-toe, to-mah-toe.

Comment: Thanks. That works so far. Unfortunately there is still a error in JUnit test which has something to do with that.

Answer (score -1):

@popdemic It´s a error in this section in the 4th line (assertEquals(40.f....)

```
 private void testSoldCarAttributes(byte vehicleType, final Vehicle v) {
    switch (vehicleType) {
        case VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR:
            assertEquals(40.f, v.getFuel(), DELTA_FLOAT);
            assertEquals(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR, v.getVehicleType());
            break;
        case VehicleType.TRUCK:
            assertEquals(80.f, v.getFuel(), DELTA_FLOAT);
            assertEquals(VehicleType.TRUCK, v.getVehicleType());
    }
```

and here in the second line testSoldCarAttributes(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR.....

```
 public void testSoldCarAttributes() {
    testSoldCarAttributes(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR, trader.sellVehicle(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR));
    testSoldCarAttributes(VehicleType.TRUCK, trader.sellVehicle(VehicleType.TRUCK));
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional errors, not an answer